# Searching for a value in struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, search, for-loop, struct

I am having a large struct array with following fields:

```
x
y
z_value
level
```

and I need to perform a search based on the condition like `z_value == 10 && level = 5`.

Currently my code loops from the first element to the last checking all the struct values.
Since the array is large its taking `~80secs` to complete.

Is there any `other alternative(other than by using binary search,heap etc)` to make this fast   **by exploiting in build features of matlab**??

Comment: Are all those data in all the fields of that struct, double data or could there be any char data too?

Comment: there are no character data in the struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the struct to have only double data, this code would get all those indices where the mentioned condition is satisfied -

```
names = fieldnames(s1) %%//s1 is your input struct

%%// matdata = cell2mat(squeeze(struct2cell(s1)))' %%//' Approach -1
matdata = reshape(struct2array(s1),numel(names),[])' %%//' Approach -2
data1 = matdata(:,[find(strcmp(names,'z_value')) find(strcmp(names,'level'))])
index = find(ismember(data1,[10 5],'rows')) %%// indices where condition is met
```

Comment: forgot to mention that struct contains integers and double. More precisely z_value is double and rest are integers.Cause problem when converting to matrix

Comment: It should be fine! Test it out and I am hoping that approach-2 would be faster.

Comment: "All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type"

Comment: double and integers comes under the same datatype called "double". So, it mostly looks like you have something else in there, might be char or complex or might be even other structs or even cells. Please investigate again on this.